# How to remove items from a list based upon certain conditions

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects and each object in the list has the following properties:

- FileName,
- SwVersion,
- ControllerSN,
- FirstDoseTime,
- EvtTime,
- Evt,
- EvtOutput

First I need to find all of the objects that have their FirstDoseTime property set to a specific value (1/1/1, 12:00:00). Let's call these blankFirstDose objects.

Then, I need to search through the list and see if for each blankFirstDose object, there is another object in the list that has the same exact properties as the blankFirstDose object except for the FirstDoseTime property (anything other than 1/1/1, 12:00:00) and the FileName property.

Finally, I want to remove any blankFirstDose objects from the list that have a corresponding object in the list that has a different FileName and a FirstDoseTime that is something other than 1/1/1, 12:00:00.

Here is my first pass at doing so. This attempt works successfully, but takes far too long when I have a large list of these objects. I need something that is more efficient and much faster.
Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Profiling

I performed some system profiling for a "typical" case to help inform this discussion. In this case, the AllEvents list contains 40,928 LogFileEvent items and the blankFirstDoseLst contains 12,092 items.

The amount of time it takes to complete all of these operations on my system is approximately 16 seconds.
Almost all of those 16 seconds are spent in the two foreach loops.

```
var blankFirstDoseLst = 
    AllEvents.GroupBy(e => e.FirstDoseTime)
             .Where(g => g.FirstOrDefault().FirstDoseTime == PatientModel.DEFAULT_DATE)
             .SelectMany(g => g)
             .ToList();
List<LogFileEvent> blanksToRemove = new List<LogFileEvent>();
foreach (var evt in AllEvents)
{
    foreach (var blankEvt in blankFirstDoseLst)
    {
        if ((evt.FileName      != blankEvt.FileName) &&
            (evt.SwVersion     == blankEvt.SwVersion) &&
            (evt.ControllerSN  == blankEvt.ControllerSN) &&
            (evt.FirstDoseTime != blankEvt.FirstDoseTime) &&
            (evt.EvtTime       == blankEvt.EvtTime) &&
            (evt.Evt           == blankEvt.Evt) &&
            (evt.EvtOutput     == blankEvt.EvtOutput))
        {
            blanksToRemove.Add(blankEvt);
        }
    }
}

// Remove any duplicates ignoring first dose date and time
AllEvents.RemoveAll(e => blanksToRemove.Contains(e));
```

Comment: The ToList() you do on the blankFirstDoseLst is unnecessary. This will go through your whole list and produce you a new list. You then go through it in your foreach which then iterates those items again. If you don't do the ToList() you should have few iterations through the collection... I think. Probably worth a try

Comment: Have you tried performance profiling your solution? And what is the usual case here - do you end up having a lot of items removed (e.g. more than half of `AllEvents`? And what is the locality of the removed items in the `AllEvents` collection? You may end up taking a long time removing from a big `List<>` since it is backed by an array. But we don't even know the type of `AllEvents` to start with...

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I added some profiling to the description. Also, the type of AllEvents is a List<LogFileEvent>. The LogFileEvent is the object which contains the 7 properties I listed.

Comment: Thank you for providing the specifics. The easiest option, if I understand the logic right, could be to flip the `foreach`es (outer would run through `blankFirstDoseList` and the inner one through `AllEvents`) and to put a `break;` after the `blanksToRemove` list insertion. This alters the logic though so please check whether it still works. It should reduce the count of iterations a bit and hopefully be enough.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Thanks for the suggestion! That is a good idea and it certainly can improve the speed in certain circumstances. The one situation where this improvement does not help, however, is in the case where there actually are no blankEvt's that meet the conditions to be removed (which can happend). In that case, it will still end up iterating through the entirety of both lists.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm afraid you're not getting to solve this without more sophisticated data structures then. If you're up for it, the first step I'd do is to have a `HashSet` with a custom `EqualityComparer` that implements the `if` condition, populated with the `blanksToRemove` and checking it for each of the `AllEvents`. This should eliminate whole subtrees and get you to O(n) checks if I'm correct. If that doesn't work well, perhaps the `AllEvents` collection could be constructed in a different manner that would allow the elimination you want in a different way?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Yeah, I'm actually in the middle of doing something just like that, thank you for the suggestion. At this point, I'm thinking that is probably the next best thing to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses I received. I ended up using a hashset strategy with a custom IEqualityComparer similar to what @ZdeněkJelínek mentioned. The custom IEqualityComparer implements the checks I was previously doing in the "if" statement.

This has significantly reduced the amount of processing time down from 16s to about 1s.

```
            // Remove any events with blank first dose time if there is a duplicate that has
            // a valid first dose time
            var blanksToRemove        = new List<LogFileEvent>();
            var blankFirstDoseEvts    = AllEvents.Where(e => e.FirstDoseTime == PatientModel.DEFAULT_DATE)
                                                 .ToList();
            var nonBlankFirstDoseEvts = new HashSet<LogFileEvent>(AllEvents.Where(e => e.FirstDoseTime != PatientModel.DEFAULT_DATE),
                                                                  new BlankFirstDoseComparer());

            foreach (var blankEvt in blankFirstDoseEvts)
            {
                if (nonBlankFirstDoseEvts.Contains(blankEvt))
                {
                    blanksToRemove.Add(blankEvt);
                }
            }

            AllEvents.RemoveAll(e => blanksToRemove.Contains(e));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of a HashSet for keeping the blanks that should be removed.

```
var blanksToRemove = new HashSet<LogFileEvent>();
```

Then the `Contains`

```
AllEvents.RemoveAll(e => blanksToRemove.Contains(e));
```

would be an O(1) operation, avoiding the linear search that it has to be done, when you use a List. In case of using a list the time complexity of Contains it is of the order of O(n), where n is the number of items in your list.

**Update**

Another change that you could make it is the following. Since you want

> ...to search through the list and see if for each blankFirstDose
>   object, there is another object in the list that has the same exact
>   properties as the blankFirstDose object except for the FirstDoseTime
>   property (anything other than 1/1/1, 12:00:00) and the FileName
>   property.

You could eliminate the items of the first foreach statement as below:

```
foreach (var evt in AllEvents.Where(evt=>evt.FirstDoseTime != PatientModel.DEFAULT_DATE))
{
    foreach (var blankEvt in blankFirstDoseLst)
    {
        if ((evt.FileName      != blankEvt.FileName) &&
            (evt.SwVersion     == blankEvt.SwVersion) &&
            (evt.ControllerSN  == blankEvt.ControllerSN) &&
            (evt.EvtTime       == blankEvt.EvtTime) &&
            (evt.Evt           == blankEvt.Evt) &&
            (evt.EvtOutput     == blankEvt.EvtOutput))
        {
            blanksToRemove.Add(blankEvt);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so you will avoid to loop through the items in `blankFirstDoseLst` for the items `AllEvents` that have as a `FirstDoseTime` a different than the value you are looking for.

Comment: I added some performance info to the description. When I use the HashSet instead of the List as you recommended it brings the operation time of 16 seconds to approximately 15.25 seconds. As I mentioned in my edit, most of the time is spent in the two foreach loops; that's the area I need to optimize.

Comment: Nice, your updated suggestion is a good one and does cut down on the number of iterations that need to be performed.

Comment: @Dustin Thanks. In terms of seconds what's the improvement? Did you notice a greater improvement than 16s->15.25s?

Comment: Under the scenario I am testing with, this improved the time from 16s -> 13s. On a different note, one thing I ended up doing that drastically cut the time down was first removing any duplicates in the AllEvents list before doing any of the above operations. At least in this one test scenario, that cut the time down to about 6s. As per another commenters input, I am going to look into using a hash table to replace the main "if" statement. I am hoping that will cut things down even more.